# Instead Join in SQL what should use in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have two collection in `MongoDB` database, i want join two Collection in PHP
I have searched but unfortunately I have not found a compelling answer.
Data look like this:

```
users
{
"_id": "4ca30369fd0e910ecc000006",
"login": "user11",
"pass": "example_pass",
"date": "2017-12-15"
}

news
"_id": "4ca305c2fd0e910ecc000003",
"name": "news 333",
"content": "news content",
"user_id": "4ca30373fd0e910ecc000007",
"date": "2017-12-15"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974024/what-should-use-instead-join-in-mongodb) thread

**Note : I'm a MEAN developer**

In mean we use `.populate()` method (mongoose) to achieve joins upto a level.

as for php

You can use different approach from RDBMS

**Data Replication**

```
"news": {
  "_id": "4ca305c2fd0e910ecc000003",
  "name": "news one",
  "content": "news one",
  "user": {
    "_id": "4ca30369fd0e910ecc000006",
    "login": "user11"
  },
  "date": "2017-12-15"
}
```