# What should I use instead of Join in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have collections in `MongoDB` database, i want to write query to join collections in `PHP`.

I want to show the news for relevant user.

I have searched but unfortunately I have not found a compelling answer.

Data look like this:

```
users
{
"_id": "4ca30369fd0e910ecc000006",
"login": "user11",
"pass": "example_pass",
"date": "2017-12-15"
}
news
{
"_id": "4ca305c2fd0e910ecc000003",
"name": "news one",
"content": "news one",
"user_id": "4ca30373fd0e910ecc000007",
"date": "2017-12-15"
}
```

Comment: check this out, https://tkacz.pro/phpmongo-using-join-in-queries/

Answer (score 0):

**Note : I'm a MEAN developer**

In mean we use `.populate()` method (mongoose) to achieve joins upto a level.

as for php

You can use different approach from RDBMS

**Data Replication**

```
"news": {
  "_id": "4ca305c2fd0e910ecc000003",
  "name": "news one",
  "content": "news one",
  "user": {
    "_id": "4ca30369fd0e910ecc000006",
    "login": "user11"
  },
  "date": "2017-12-15"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement joins in mongodb using *mongoose* *.populate()* is the one way. If you want to implement joins at MongoDB database level then you should try **aggregation** pipeline and **$lookup**

```
db.news.aggregate([ 
  $lookup : { 
  from : 'users', 
  localField : 'user_id', 
  foreignField : '_id', 
  as : 'user' 
 } 
])
```

You can use *$match* to add condition and filter the result of query.